# I Cannot Update my database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Whats wrong with these?

My module is:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1
    Public con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\CITeval\system7\system7\evaluation.mdb")
    Public da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader
    Public cmd As OleDbCommand
    Public ds = New DataSet
    Public CurrentRow As Integer
    Public sql As String
End Module
```

btn update

```
Try
    Dim Str As String
    Str = "update studentsrecord set IDNumber="
    Str += """" & txtIDNumber.Text & """"
    Str += " where IDNumber="
    Str += txtIDNumber.Text.Trim()
    con.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    con.Open()
    Str = "update studentsrecord set FirstName="
    Str += """" & txtfirst.Text & """"
    Str += " where IDNumber="
    Str += txtIDNumber.Text.Trim()
    con.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    con.Open()
    Str = "update studentsrecord set LastName="
    Str += """" & txtlast.Text & """"
    Str += " where IDNumber="
    Str += txtfirst.Text.Trim()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    con.Open()
    Str = "UPDATE studentsrecord set Course="
    Str += """" & cbocourse.Text & """"
    Str += " where IDNumber="
    Str += txtIDNumber.Text.Trim()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    con.Open()
    Str = "update studentsrecord set Password="
    Str += """" & txtpassword.Text & """"
    Str += " where IDNumber="
    Str += txtIDNumber.Text.Trim()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
    ds.Clear()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM studentsrecord ORDER BY ID", con)
    da.Fill(ds, "evaluation")
    MsgBox("Updated Successfully...")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message & "," & ex.Source)
Finally
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: For one, SQL uses single quotes, and you are adding doubles.

Comment: access database i am using

Comment: Ah, OK. Please add the Access tag to the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: the problem is was NOT CLOSEd. The Connection's current state is open .,System.Data

Comment: Error message you getting kind what?

Comment: Also, you can avoid all that string concatenation and make it far more readable with [OleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx)

Comment: @yuriy the problem is was NOT CLOSEd. The Connection's current state is open .,System.Data

Comment: @valverij im newbie in vb.,.,SORRY

Comment: So the problem is solved now? BTW you don't need to close your connection between updates. Better yet combine all your updates into batches.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter can u give me a sample code my problem is not solved.,.,.,

Comment: @JohnChristopherReguindin I answered with code sample

Comment: @John Christopher Reguindin  What kind of error messages are you getting... we are still not clear how to help you.

Comment: System error UPDATE statement.,Microsoft Jet database Engine it says:(

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to issue a separate UPDATE statement for each field, you can update multiple fields in a single UPDATE statement. Also a better choice is to use parametrized query instead of concatenating strings.

Try this inside of your TRY/CATCH block:

```
Dim Str As String
Str = "update studentsrecord set FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName,  Course = @Course, Password = @Password  where IDNumber = @IDNumber "
cmd = New OleDbCommand(Str, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtfirst.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtlast.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", cbocourse.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtpassword.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNumber", txtIDNumber.Text.Trim())

con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

ds.Clear()
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM studentsrecord ORDER BY ID", con)
da.Fill(ds, "evaluation")

MsgBox("Updated Successfully...")
```

Comment: i've tried the code code above and  it gives me this:

System error UPDATE statement.,Microsoft Jet database Engine

it says:(

Comment: That's it, no more  specifics? Ok try to build your SQL like this:  `Str = "update studentsrecord set FirstName = ?, LastName = ?,  Course = ?, Password = ?  where IDNumber = ?"`

Comment: This is what I did in my answer. With possible alternative in my previous comment.

Comment: System error or syntax error? What is the ***exact*** error message? Can you copy it and add to your question? Can you also add to your updated code that causes the error?

Comment: add me in facebook sir.,.,.,so we could dscuss., inverse_killer99@yahoo.com

Comment: Sorry I don't use facebook